Listen to the change of userData in JavaFX
I want to listen to the change of userData of a stage in JavaFX. I have tried to wrap the Object which is returned from getUserData method inside a SimpleObjectProperty, then add a listener to it but it didn't work.
This is my attempt:
SimpleObjectProperty<Object> userDataProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(stage.getUserData());
    userDataProperty.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // print when userData is changed
    System.out.println("new userdata:" + stage.getUserData());
});

// change the userData to test if the listener work
stage.setUserData(2);
System.out.println(stage.getUserData());
stage.setUserData(3);
System.out.println(stage.getUserData());

Output:
2
3

How to do it properly?

@James_D I don't have userDataProperty() method for stage. The compiler said it couldn't resolve that method.

Ah ok. I didn’t have access to the documentation when I wrote that. I’ll delete it.

The Window class does not expose a JavaFX property for the user data, which means it is not directly observable. However, the Window#setUserData(Object) method has this somewhat cryptic documentation:

Convenience method for setting a single Object property that can be retrieved at a later date. This is functionally equivalent to calling the getProperties().put(Object key, Object value) method. This can later be retrieved by calling getUserData().

That would seem to indicate the user data is held in the ObservableMap returned by Window#getProperties(). And if you look at the implementation, you will see that is indeed the case. Unfortunately, the key for the user data entry is private. But you can use reflection to get the key or, possibly better, use a MapChangeListener to capture it.
Once you have the key you can use Bindings#valueAt(ObservableMap, K) to create an ObjectBinding that will always report the latest user data value.
Here is an example where a MapChangeListener is used to capture the key.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding;
import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class Main extends Application {

  // Make sure to keep a strong reference to the binding for as long as you need it.
  private ObjectBinding<Object> userData;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    userData = userDataBinding(primaryStage);
    // Note: Using _ for unused parameters was standardized in Java 22.
    userData.addListener(
        (_, oldVal, newVal) -> System.out.printf("User data: %s -> %s%n", oldVal, newVal));

    // Type something into the TextField then press ENTER to see the example at work.
    var field = new TextField();
    field.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    field.setOnAction(
        e -> {
          e.consume();
          primaryStage.setUserData(field.getText());
          field.clear();
        });

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(field), 500, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private ObjectBinding<Object> userDataBinding(Window window) {
    // Use array because local variables must be (effectively) final when used inside
    // a lambda expression or anonymous class.
    var keyHolder = new Object[1];
    window
        .getProperties()
        .addListener(
            new MapChangeListener<>() {
              @Override
              public void onChanged(Change<? extends Object, ? extends Object> change) {
                keyHolder[0] = change.getKey();
                // Only need to capture the key once.
                change.getMap().removeListener(this);
              }
            });
    var oldUserData = window.getUserData(); // save current value
    window.setUserData(new Object());       // invoke the listener
    window.setUserData(oldUserData);        // restore to old value
    return Bindings.valueAt(window.getProperties(), keyHolder[0]);
  }
}

From looking at the documentation, the same approach can be used with Scene and Node.

Of course, you could use your own key and manipulate the Window.getProperties() map directly. That will likely be easier.

This solution will also invoke the listener when the userData isn't changed, but another property of stage is changed. Am I correct?

The ObjectBinding returned by userDataBinding will be invalidated whenever the ObservableMap is invalidated, yes. Though a ChangeListener on the map should only be invoked when the value mapped to the user data key truly changes. And other properties of the window/stage, such as showing, title, scene, etc., are not related to the ObservableMap (i.e., changing them won't invalidate the map).

Could you elaborate on why we only need to capture the key once?

Because setUserData and getUserData have to use the same key every time (at least by equals, but in this case the key is actually a constant held in a private static final field). And once we have the key its immediately passed to Bindings.valueAt(...). From then on, the returned ObjectBinding will observe the ObservableMap in order to always report the most recent value mapped to the given key.

Small correction for first comment: Meant to say "... a ChangeListener on the object binding should ...".
